# WebRTC instead of UDP stream on webpage to remove VLC Player

Tags: javascript, html, udp, webrtc, vlc

Is it possible to stream life broadcast video on closed network via WebRTC to webpage 1-many? I used to use VLC and UDP streaming for life video, but all browsers discontinued support for VLC plugin and HTML5 video does not support life streaming. The goal is to use webpage for life video streaming when users  only watch that page (no 2 way communication).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

This will be more expensive to do (processing power and servers that you'll need), but definitely possible.

Janus and Jitsi are used a lot for it. Red5Pro, nanocosmos and Wowza seem to have suitable offerings in this domain as well.